# How to fill a binary matrix in opencv using C++

Tags: c++, opencv

I want to fill a matrix dest from another matrix which named fgMask,so I write this program:

```
Mat dest;
dest.create(fgMask.size(),fgMask.type());
dest=cv::Scalar(0.0f);


for(int i=4;i<fgMask.rows-4;++i){
    for(int j=4;j<fgMask.cols-4;++j){
        bool white = true;
        for(int k=c.x;i<c.width;++k){
            for(int l=c.y;l<c.height;++l){
                if(fgMask.at<uchar>(k,l)>0){

                    white=false;
                }
                if(white){  
                    dest.at<uchar>(i,j)=255;
                }
                else
                {

                    dest.at<uchar>(i,j)=0;
                }                               
            }               
        }

    }       
}

return dest;
```

But when I debug it I got that :

```
 Mat dest;
(gdb) n
56      dest.create(fgMask.size(),fgMask.type());
(gdb) n
57      dest=cv::Scalar(0.0f);
(gdb) 
60      for(int i=4;i<fgMask.rows-4;++i){
(gdb) 
61          for(int j=4;j<fgMask.cols-4;++j){
(gdb) 
62              bool white = true;
(gdb) 
63              for(int k=c.x;i<c.width;++k){
(gdb) 
64                  for(int l=c.y;l<c.height;++l){
(gdb) 
63              for(int k=c.x;i<c.width;++k){
(gdb) 
64                  for(int l=c.y;l<c.height;++l){
(gdb) 
63              for(int k=c.x;i<c.width;++k){
(gdb) 
64                  for(int l=c.y;l<c.height;++l){
(gdb) 
63              for(int k=c.x;i<c.width;++k){
(gdb) 
64                  for(int l=c.y;l<c.height;++l){
(gdb) 
63              for(int k=c.x;i<c.width;++k){
(gdb) 
64                  for(int l=c.y;l<c.height;++l){
(gdb) 
63              for(int k=c.x;i<c.width;++k){
(gdb) 
64                  for(int l=c.y;l<c.height;++l){
(gdb) 
63              for(int k=c.x;i<c.width;++k){
(gdb) 
64                  for(int l=c.y;l<c.height;++l){
(gdb) 
63              for(int k=c.x;i<c.width;++k){
(gdb) 
64                  for(int l=c.y;l<c.height;++l){
(gdb) 
63              for(int k=c.x;i<c.width;++k){
(gdb) 
64                  for(int l=c.y;l<c.height;++l){
(gdb)
```

it can't enter to the loop to fill the matrix.Can anyone know what is my mistakes?

Comment: print out the values and see why c.y isn't < c.height.   you didn't post enough code for anyone to tell you more than that.

Comment: why not just use `Mat1b dest(fgMask.rows, fgMask.cols, uchar(0)); dest.setTo(255, fgMask == 0);`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see 2 errors in your code:

There is one here `;i<c.width;`. it should be `;k<c.width;`

and another error here `fgMask.at<uchar>(k,l)`

`k` refers to the width, so in a way of speaking is the columns, and `l` refers to the rows, so it should be:

`fgMask.at<uchar>(l,k)`

also, you should give some more info, like how is `cv::Rect c`intialized ? it could be anything...